# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, html, database

i'm trying to connect to my database and this error is displayed. i am using a paid server for my database.

```
function connect_to_database()
{
    $username = "treq";
    $password = "treq";
    $hostname = "89.46.2.250";
    $database = "tr";
    $con = mysqli_connect($username, $password, $hostname, $database) or die ("Connecting to MySQL failed");
    return $con;
}
```

Comment: You just put your credentials on a site with millions of users

Comment: i have modified them relax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed the connect parameters, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

```
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database) or die ("Connecting to MySQL failed");
```

First parameter is hostname, then username and password.